# JAVA linkedlist adding a node at second position

Tags: java

i recently started learning java and was wondering how i could edit the code so that the node is inserted at the second position rather than the middle as seen in the code. ive tried everything but nothing seemed to work.

```
static void insertAtMid(int x) 
    { 

        if (head == null) 
            head = new Node(x); 
        else { 

            Node newNode = new Node(x); 

            Node ptr = head; 
            int len = 0; 


            while (ptr != null) { 
                len++; 
                ptr = ptr.next; 
            } 


            int count = ((len % 2) == 0) ? (len / 2) : 
                                        (len + 1) / 2; 
            ptr = head; 


            while (count-- > 1) 
                ptr = ptr.next; 


            newNode.next = ptr.next; 
            ptr.next = newNode; 
        } 
    } 

    static void display() 
    { 
        Node temp = head; 
        while (temp != null)  
        { 
            System.out.print(temp.data + " "); 
            temp = temp.next; 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main (String[] args)  
    {  

        head = null; 
        head = new Node(1); 
        head.next = new Node(2); 
        head.next.next = new Node(4); 
        head.next.next.next = new Node(5); 

        System.out.println("Linked list before "+ 
                           "insertion: "); 
        display(); 

        int x = 3; 
        insertAtMid(x); 

        System.out.println("\nLinked list after"+ 
                           " insertion: "); 
        display(); 
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
int count = ((len % 2) == 0) ? (len / 2) : (len + 1) / 2;
```

to

```
int count = (len >=1)? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to delete most of the method:

```
    static void insertSecond(int x) 
    { 

        if (head == null) 
            head = new Node(x); 
        else { 

            Node newNode = new Node(x); 

            newNode.next = head.next; 
            head.next = newNode; 
        } 
    }
```

EDIT: got more than deletion, since I deleted stupid

> ptr = head;